# How to merge cells in a in a column in table if cells are having same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I do have a table containing same value in many of the cells in a column.

I would like to merge cells having same value. Could you please help on how to merge cells in a table based on cell value.

Actual tabel is below:

ITEM-QUANTITY
Apple-3
Apple-4
Orange-5

This should be brought as 
Item-Quantity
Apple-3
-4
Orange-5

Comment: Provide an example of how you want to merge & share what you have already tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex table merging javascript & jquery algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181596/complex-table-merging-javascript-jquery-algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to implement your own matching algorithm. Once you have done that, use the colspan attribute to merge them. eg if apple is in 3 and 4 cells, then that cell could be <td colspan='2'>apple</td>